# Disable submit form of Gravity form after 10 entries with a field with specific value

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

How i can disable submit form after 10 entries with a field with specific value?

Example:
Field checkbox "Privacy":
Agree
Not agree

After 10 entries of field "Privacy" with value agree, form dissapear and show message "finished inscriptions" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a simple code solution for this but our [Gravity Forms Limit Submissions](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-limit-submissions/#field-value) plugin handles limiting a form by field value. When the limit is reached, you can display a custom message in place of the form.